# Flink deserialize Kafka message error doesn't ignore message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a Flink (v1.15) pipeline implementing a custom AbstractDeserializationSchema.

An exception is thrown for a bad message in the deserialize(byte[] message) method whereby I catch the exception and simply return null.

According to the Flink docs (see below) returning null should cause Flink to ignore this message and move onto the next. My example doesn't and reprocesses the message continuously.

Here is a sample of my deserializer. I did some debugging and it does indeed step into the if block and it returns null. The message is then simply reprocessed over and over.

[image]

According to the official Flink docs (v1.13 and below) returning null should cause Flink to ignore this message.

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/

This exceprt below is from the above link (v1.13) and I noticed from v1.14 / v1.15 on this has been removed (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/)

[image]

This is the repeated flow of the task after the XML parsing error

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I understand that the task doesn't fail and restarts, is that right? It just keeps processing the same message all the time. How do you know that it is always processing the same message?

Comment: Yes, it simply reprocesses the same message over and over. I can view the Kafka topic with the messages I am expecting to consume and they never change. The XML parsing error I am seeing is because of a 'bad' message I added which is not XML and it remains on the topic.

Comment: The messages in a Kafka topic do not disappear when consumed.

Comment: OK, that makes sense on that part. I think then the Flink offset is not incremented. Does this seem to be more likely? Also, the Flink task manager pod doesn't restart ever. 

Another error I see after the XML parsing error is

`Transiting to fatal error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: There is a newer producer with the same transactionalId which fences the current one`

while the original error is

`com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '1' (code 49) in prolog; expected '<'` which means it's failing to parse XML

Comment: yep, that makes more sense. Note that the task may restart even if the Task Manager pod never restarts (you can see it in the job manager webui for example). The other error seems to indicate that it will actually restart (a fatal error most likely produces a task restart). Do you have multiple producers with the same transactionalId running at the same time or in the same task?

Comment: So at no point am I actually producing to the topic. It's an upstream system I have no context of. They dumped this rogue message onto the topic when testing and everything has halted now.

I only have this Flink deployment running in the cluster on this topic currently.

Comment: And you are not producing to any topic?

Comment: I do produce to a topic downstream on a sink but not to this upstream topic. Source->pipeline->sink.